# Google Maps: Unable to add auto search options in map contains marks from database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, autocomplete

I am trying to add store markers from database in Google map, and auto search option to zoom the particular location.

I am able to add markers from database, but i am unable to add auto search options in map contains marks from database.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Maplocator.aspx.cs" Inherits="Maplocator" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Show/Add multiple markers to Google Maps from database in asp.net website</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            var input = (document.getElementById('txtsearch'));
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));


            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });


                (function(marker, data) {

                    // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.Descriptions);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                    var bounds = map.getBounds();
                    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
                });
            }

        }
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div style="width: 500px; height: 200px"> </div>
        <input id="txtsearch" class="apply" type="text" placeholder="Enter Search Place e.g C# Corner Noida" />
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 500px"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
 public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title=City,lat=latitude,lng=longitude,Descriptions from LocationDetails", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Place Autocomplete Results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results)

> The Place Autocomplete response does not include the scope or alt_ids fields that you may see in search results or place details. This is because Autocomplete returns only Google-scoped place IDs. **It does not return app-scoped place IDs that have not yet been accepted into the Google Places database.**

Additionally, when you [add a place](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place),

> the new place also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps.

That means, you only get to see those added markers or places in auto search option if they passed the moderation process and are being accepted into Google Places database.

**Important Note:**

> To make it more likely that the place will pass the moderation process and be added to the Google Maps database, the add request should include as much information as possible. In particular, the following fields are most likely to improve the chances of passing the moderation process: phone number, address and website.